# Need some help with terminal

Tags: 12.04

I want to Open terminal to certain location with certain commands executed something like

example (file name click to open terminal and execute commands below)

```
cd folder\folder
. venv/bin/activate
```

after this terminal should remain open

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  Is your terminal closing after you run your command?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you want it to do this occasionally, or all of the time?

Answer (score 1):

Run `nano terminal-command-script` in terminal, in your home directory.

Copy this, and paste it in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and edit it to what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd folder\folder
. venv/bin/activate
```

Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then run `chmod +x terminal-command-script`, and open up File browser to your home directory.
There should be a file in there called `teminal-command-script` - click on it, and hopefully you will get something like this:

[image: prompt]

This is how you can get Terminal to open with it - alternately you could edit the launcher in `/usr/share/applications/` so it would **always** open with it - *(well. perhaps when you press the button, might not work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)*.

---

<sub>I have not tested this, and it is probably the wrong answer anyway, but I can't spend all my time here, sorry :-)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly this is what you are asking.
your asking if you can have a program that does a few commands including opening a terminal.

You can always create a script (.sh) 
so write in something like this

```
    cd ~/Desktop
    nano Scriptname.sh #you can change the script name to whatever you want
```

edit the script so it looks like this (it'll start blank)

```
     gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"cd folder/folder; exec bash\""
```

You just have to run bash inside the script so that the terminal remains open and make sure to have exec bash at the end....

source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution